# how to make clicked image large and other image as it is

Tags: android

suppose i have five images in a row in linearlayout. images from drawable,now i want to do like while user click on image it will be large and other will be same size as it is.i have searched in google but no such solution found. how to do that?

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/smileyLayoutId"
            android:padding="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/smiley1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/smileyImageId1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/smiley2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/smileyImageId2"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/smiley3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/smileyImageId3"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/smiley4"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/smileyImageId4"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/smiley5"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/smileyImageId5"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/smiley6"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/smileyImageId6"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
```

so can you please do this ?

Comment: You can open new activity with large imageview ? OR any other requirements ?

Comment: same activity to implement